# How can i prevent the search results div from closing when clicking inside of it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a jsfiddle for this question. https://jsfiddle.net/1af4gyt5/

If you type inside the search input then you will see the search results. I made a overlay which is important to stay, if i click outside the search input the overlay will hide. And if i focus inside of it it will show. But i have been hours and hours trying to make the search results DIV NOT to close if i click inside the results DIV `<a> LINK:aaaaaaa</a> etc.`.

Can someone please help me to prevent the search results DIV(`#show_search`) to close when i click on the links inside the search results DIV(`#show_search`). I also want it working in combination of the overlay effect on the search input.

Thank you very much for your time, appreciate it!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>

  #show_search{
    width: 506px;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
z-index:1;
    }
  #show_search a{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
    padding:10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:1;
    background:yellow;
  }
  #search {
    z-index:1;
  }

  #overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: -1;
    cursor: default;
  }
  </style>
<div id="overlay"></div>
<form class="form-inline my-0"><div class="form-group has-search">
<span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback"></span>
<input id='search' type="text" class="form-control input-more-width" placeholder="Search">
</div></form><div class="show_search" id="show_search"><a>LINK:aaaaaa</a><a>LINK:bbbbbbb</a><a>LINK:cccccccc</a></div>

<script>
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
$("#show_search").show();
  });

  $('#search').focus(function() {
  $("#overlay").show();
  $("#search").keyup(function(){
    $("#overlay").show();
  $('#search').focusout(function() {
  $(".show_search").hide();
  $("#overlay").hide();
        });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `$('#search').focusout` handler, which gets called whenever you click a link in `#show_search` (or do *anything* to remove focus from the search box), as that includes

```
$(".show_search").hide();
```

which hides the search results box.

To make the `#show_search` box hide when you click outside it or outside the `#search` input, add a `click` handler to the entire page and check that the click is not inside one of those elements; if it isn't, close the `#show_search` box:

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest("#search").length === 0 && $(e.target).closest("#show_search").length === 0) {
        $('#show_search').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. Yes i understand that, but then the `#show_search` doesn't HIDE when the user clicks outside of the search input and it doesn't HIDE when clicking outside of the `#show_search`. That's what i have been struggling with.

Comment: @Poemko I've added code to the answer which will close the `#show_search` box if the user clicks outside it or the search box.